# Подскажите нормативные документы по учёту версий ПО

Tags: документация

Нужны ГОСТ или инструкции по учёту версий ПО, может быть кто-нибудь знает эти документы?

Comment: О правилах ведения программной документации нам говорит знаменитая группа ГОСТов 19.***.

Comment: В этой группе гостов нет информации о версиях программ. Там не предусмотрено развитие программы в процессе эксплуатации.

Comment: Других ГОСТов по программной документации в России нет. :-) Обычно делают так - в название программы включают номер версии программы. Правда, при  таком подходе приходится перевыпускать Спецификацию каждый раз, когда выходит новая версия. Но зато пользователи всегда могут проверить, последней ли версией они пользуются.