# Когда должен меняться номер редакции/издания программы?

Tags: документация

В соответствии с ГОСТ 19.103 в обозначение программного документа включается "номер редакции документа". Например, в обозначении спецификации АААА.00001-02 это номер 02, в обозначении руководства оператора АААА.00001-04 13 01 это номер 04. Но ни в одном стандарте ЕСПД я не нашёл указаний о том, в каких случаях номер редакции должен меняться, и как он зависит от номера изменения.

Имеются ответы службы поддержки АО "Кодекс" (Техэксперт), в которых говорится, что номер редакции меняется во всех случаях, когда внесение изменений проводится способом, отличным от аннулирования документа с заменой новым. В остальных случаях меняется номер изменения. Однако ссылок на соответствующие пункты стандартов эксперты не приводят.

Подобное содержится и в комментариях к [этому вопросу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1051346/3380), и справедливо отмечено, что при таком подходе при каждом изменении программного документа приходится перевыпускать спецификацию.

На мой взгляд, такой подход совершенно несостоятельный, так как изменив один программный документ, отличный от текста программы, мы получим, что номер редакции спецификации отличается от номера издания программы, что запрещено пунктом 9 ГОСТ 19.103.

Второй причиной недопустимости такого подхода является невозможность простановки литеры (а это обязательно в военном ПО), так как в решении об утверждении изменений в программной документации будет указан документ, например, АААА.00001-01 13 01, но при простановке литеры его обозначение изменится на АААА.00001-02 13 01. И становится непонятно, на какой документ мы проставили литеру.

Скорее всего, практика изменения номера редакции программного документа сложилась на местах работы экспертов, но не закреплена в ГОСТ.

Вопрос: возможно, я плохо прочитал ГОСТ. Где в нём указано, в каких случаях должен изменяться номер редакции программного документа? Если всё же такого нет, то какой подход используется в вашей организации?